# pass Data from Ms-access to crystal reports to Details section vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, crystal-reports

I want to pass values to Crystal Reports from MS-Access DB.

Problem is Crystal Reports shows last Row only, so the parameters forget the other rows and take the last only !

NB : those parameters set on Details section in Crystal Reports.
My code :

```
Try
    StockForm.DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DBConnect().selectdata(String.Format("SELECT  SellingDetails.FacID, SellingDetails.Item, SellingDetails.UnitPrice, SellingDetails.Qnt, SellingDetails.TotalPrice FROM SellingDetails where SellingDetails.FacID like '%{0}%'", SellingForm.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value))
    For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        Report1.SetParameterValue("Item", dt.Rows(i)(1))
        Report1.SetParameterValue("Qnt", dt.Rows(i)(2))
        Report1.SetParameterValue("UnitPrice", dt.Rows(i)(3))
        Report1.SetParameterValue("TotalPrice", dt.Rows(i)(4))
        MsgBox(dt.Rows(i)(1))
    Next
    dt.Dispose()
    dt = Nothing
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

Comment: Already advised in deleted question to use DataTable as ReportSource. Why would that not work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33974747/crystal-report-data-source-from-datagridview-datasource

Comment: no isnt work @June7

Comment: Looping data is certainly not going to work. Review https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Crystal-Report-ASPNet-Example-using-DataSet-or-DataTable-in-C-VBNet-and-Visual-Studio-2010.aspx